# Is there a simple approach to calculate the integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $H = \{(x,y,z)|~z > 0 \text{ and } x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2 \}$.

Let $F : \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^3$ be the vector field
$$F(x,y,z) =(~x^2 (y^2 − z^3), ~xzy^4 + e^{−x^2}y^4+y,~ x^2y(y^2x^3 + 3)z + e^{−x^
2−y^2} )$$
Compute 
$$\int_H F\cdot \hat{n} ~\mathrm{d}S$$where $\hat{n}$ is the outward (upward) pointing unit surface normal and $\mathrm{d}S$
is the area element.

---

My attempt:

The vector field $F$ is really complicated, and I want to find some way with little computational work. I try the divergence theorem. But $H$ is not the boundary of a closed region. And if we add the $xy$-plane, the computation becomes more complicated.

Comment: Suggestion: The outward unit normal field is $(x, y, z)/R$. Compute the dot product, then use symmetry; particularly, if a function is odd in $x$ or odd in $y$, its integral over your hemisphere vanishes.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you! Using symmetry is critical.

Comment: @user5579085 do you have some misunderstanding about the definition of "duplicate" or your time arrow is reversing, Mr. "$100 is nothing"?