# How to compute $\int_H F\cdot n \, dS$ efficiently?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $H=\{(x,y,z):z>0, x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2\}$ and $$F(x,y,z)=(x^2(y^2-z^3),xzy^4+e^{-x^2}y^4+y,x^2y(y^2x^3+3)z+e^{-x^2-y^2})$$

Find $\int_H F\cdot n\,dS$ where $n$ is the outward unit normal and $dS$ is the area element.

I believe $$\int_H F\cdot n\,dS=\iint_DF\cdot(r_\phi\times r_\theta) \, dA$$ where $$r(\phi,\theta)=R(\sin\phi\cos\theta,\sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\phi).$$

(Or do I need to add the integral over the circle in the $z=0$ plane?)

We have $$r_\phi\times r_\theta = R^2(\sin^2\phi\cos\theta, \sin^2\phi\sin\theta, \sin\phi\cos\phi)$$

Even computing $F(r(\phi,\theta))$ yields cumbersome expressions, not to mention the dot product of $F(r(\phi,\theta))$ with $r_\phi\times r_\theta$. Is there a way to simplify this without computing? There must be some symmetry which I've always have hard time seeing and understanding. I also tried the divergence theorem, but the expressions there are cumbersome too.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881566/divergence-theorem-and-a-hemisphere?noredirect=1&lq=1 for more details on Christian Blatter's answer below.

Comment: Similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832074/a-flux-integral-evaluates-to-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351616/is-there-a-simple-approach-to-calculate-the-integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply the divergence theorem you obtain a volume integral over the upper half $B$ of the ball of radius $R$ and another surface integral over the disc $D$  of radius $R$ in the $(x,y)$-plane. Write out the integrands  in terms of $x$, $y$, $z$, and cross out all terms that vanish trivially, or by symmetry. Note that the half ball $B$ is symmetric with respect to the $x$- and $y$-axes. At the end not much will remain that actually has to be computed.

One obtains
$${\rm div}(F)=2x(y^2-z^3)+4(xz+e^{-x^2}) y^3+1+x^2 y(y^2x^3+3)\ .$$
Only the constant $1$ term gives a contribution, by symmetry. But this is not all. Gauss's theorem applies to the half ball $B$ and its *complete* boundary surface $\partial B$. One part of $\partial B$ is the surface $H$ defined in the question, and the other part is the disc $D$. We therefore have to calculate and take into account
$$\int_D F(x,y,0)\cdot(0,0,1)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_D e^{-x^2-y^2}\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ .$$
Here we can introduce polar coordinates and compute $$\int_0^R r e^{-r^2}\>dr\ .$$
Now put it all together, taking care of the signs.

Comment: I got that the divergence is $$2xy^2-2xz^3+4xzy^3+4e^{-x^2}y^3x^5y^3+3x^2y+1.$$ Am I supposed to cross out the terms that don't change upon substitution $x\to -x$, or $y\to -y$, or both $x\to -x$ and $y\to -y$? So only the terms $-2xz^3+x^5y^3$ survive? I actually don't see geometrically what's going on, so clarifying this... Also, why is there two integrals after the application of the divergence theorem? In this similar question, there is only one integral: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2831992/557906

Comment: Correction to the comment: "only $-2xz^3+1$ survives"?

Comment: Second correction to the comment. First, the term $4e^{-x^2}y^3x^5y^3$  should be $4e^{-x^2}y^3+x^5y^3$. Second, maybe instead of what I said, I should cross out the terms that change sign after one of the three transformations mentioned above? This way, only the term $1$ will remain, and in this case the integral will be half the volume of the sphere, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So I guess I need to cross out the terms that change sign after one of the three transformations I mentioned above. I decided assemble my remaining doubts into a separate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881566/divergence-theorem-and-a-hemisphere